# Convexification

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming

Suppose we have a typical minimization problem as follows:

Min $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{\left( {{a}_{i}}{{x}_{i}}-{{b}_{i}}x_{i}^{2} \right)}$

$0\leq {x}_{i}\leq {c}_{i}   \,\,\forall i$

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{x}_{i}}}=D$

here (${a}_{i}$, ${b}_{i}$, ${c}_{i}$) $\forall i=1,...,n$ and $D$ are positive parameters. ${x}_{i}$s are decision variables.

As seen, the only expression that makes the problem non-convex is the quadratic term in the objective function. In order to exploit the efficiency of convex optimization problems (having global solution), is there any way to convexify the objective function? For simplicity, suppose that ${a}_{i}$s have meaningful distances from ${b}_{i}$s, e.g. $\,\,\,\,{a}_{i} > 100{b}_{i}$.

Answer (score 3):

Our expression it's $$\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i-\sum_{i=2}^nb_ix_i^2-b_1\left(D-\sum_{i=2}^nx_i\right)^2,$$ concave of $x_i$ for any $i$ besides $1$, which says that the minimum occurs for $x_i\in\{0,c_i\}$ for $1<i\leq n$.

Comment: Dear @Michael Rosenberg,  thank you for the quick response. The first term in the objective function is not equal to yours. We can't substitute the summation over x with D in the first term.

Comment: @Hassan  Yes, it was my mistake. I fixed. But the rest is the same.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't answer my question. Why should we exclude i=1? I am looking for a method to convexify the mentioned problem.

Comment: @Hassan Because not always $D=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i,$ where $x_i\in\{0,c_i\}$.

Comment: I think something is wrong in your assumption about mistaking the index with real variable.

Comment: @Hassan  We need to choose $i$, for which $D-\sum\limits_{k\neq i}\alpha_kc_k\in[0,c_i]$, where $\alpha_k\in\{0,1\}$. I wrote that this $i$ is equal to $1$. Ask you questions. The big problem that we have a very many parameters and a solution depend on them. But the general idea with concavity it's what solves your problem in any case.